# Cloning to local directory?

Tags: git, github

I have some code on a github repository that is old. 
I have updated code in a local folder that is currently not connected to github at all. This folder contains the same filenames as the ones in the github repository, with some additional files.

I would like to push all the code in that local folder to the existing repository.

I've tried two solutions online like https://gist.github.com/davisford/5039064, 
but I'm not seeing the changes on github. This doesn't seem that complicated so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the commands you ran and the output.

Comment: what commands did you run and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

So go like that way.

It is must to come in sync before you push new code on github master/branch
Do the following

1.) Stash your local changes using command `git stash`.

2.)Pull changes from github repo using command `git pull`.

3.) Clean project or rebuild or whatever is needed based on your stack.
4.) Unstash your changes using command `git stash pop` or right click on projetc -> git -> unstash -> select your stash changes.

With that your changes will be layered over your git repo changes.

5.) `git status` you will see your changes reflecting.

6.) `git add .` or `git add <file name(s)>`

7.) git commit -m "Your message here"

8.) `git push`or `git push origin master` depending on your git scenario.

And you will be in sync once your PR is approved.